# Qt VS Tools not creating .ts file properly

Tags: visual-studio, qt, translation

Using Visual Studio 2017 and Qt VS Tools 2.7.1, I'm trying to create a new English translation file using **Solution|Qt|Create New Translation File**. A new filter appears in the Solution, called "Translation Files", with "projectname_en.ts". Seems OK. The File Properties for the file shows where it's supposed to be (i:\projectname\src\projectname_en.ts) -- But when double clicking on the file, Qt Linquist says it can't find the file specified. Looking on disk, sure enough, there is no .ts file there.

Has anyone run into this issue before? I've tried cleaning the entire project of all Qt-generated files, restarting Visual Studio, etc. but the result is always the same.